# Chrome Extension shows incorrect font size compared to the local dev testing

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I was developing an app while I was testing it on Google Chrome with react npm run, but when I Uploaded the Extension to Google to test it, something very strange happened, the fonts is showing as small, and I don't know what the problem could be. I'm using EM units and my size is 100%, the same as I had on local testing. Does someone know anything related to this and how I can fix it?

Here is how it shows on the development localhost:
[Full Browser Screenshot on Localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGrjO.jpg)

And here is how it shows when I upload to Google with 100% of the same settings I had while I tested it on localHost: [Full Browser Screenshot when I upload it on Chrome to test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJSgx.png)

Comment: Your localhost page or your extension page may have been zoomed in/out.

Comment: @wOxxOm I just checked them and they are both at 100%, I Think they should be the same, isn't zoom global?

Comment: Zoom is per site.

Comment: @wOxxOm, okay didn't know that, but is the same though

Answer (score 4):

I've faced the same problem and after digging development console I've noticed the problem.

Chrome injects a css script to body element as shown in below (only for extension pages):

```
body {
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 75%;
}
```

So adding a `font-size: 100%;` to body css can fix our problem.